# Need to hide a link and show it only if an admin is logged in

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to figure out this issue I am having.

I am trying to create a link but ONLY if there's an admin logged in, otherwise the link should be hidden.

```
if ($administrator = true) {
            echo '<a href="medewerkertoevoegen.php?id='.'">Medewerkers 
toevoegen</a>';
        }
        else 
    {
       echo '<span></span>'; 
    }
```

I am not sure if this is how it should work, currently my database looks like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fob2O.png

Please let me know if you can help me because I am very new at this, thanks!

Comment: the condition is always "true" because of the single equal.

Comment: What value does `$administrator` contains??

Answer (score 0):

Because '=' is assignation (not comparing). You must use '==' or '==='.

```
if ($administrator === true) {
    echo '<a href="medewerkertoevoegen.php?id='.'">Medewerkers 
toevoegen</a>';
} else {
    echo '<span></span>'; 
}
```